# whats the difference between these patterns?

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

I use the following pattern all of the time:

```
;(function(ns){

   var _str = 'hello';

   ns.hello = function(){
      console.log(str)
   }

})(this.app = this.app || {});

app.hello(); // logs 'hello' to the console
```

I'm trying to to do more OO type things and want to reuse this pattern. What I've come up with is the following that looks very similar to the above.

```
var App = (function(){

   var _str= 'hello';

   function App(){}

   App.prototype.hello = function(){
      console.log(_str);
   }

   return App;

})();

var instance = new App();
    instance.hello(); // logs 'hello' to the console
```

This next variation makes use of the "that" idea but i dont see the utility of it in this use case:

```
var App = (function(){
   var that = this;
   this._str= 'hello';

   function App(){}

   App.prototype.hello = function(){
      console.log(that._str);
   }

   return App;

})();
var instance = new App();
    instance.hello(); // logs 'hello' to the console
```

Is it a worthwhile to wrap things in a closure when attempting to write in an OO fashion? Any drawbacks to the above constructors? Should i focus on learning a different pattern?

Comment: A great explanation is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: What you're showing there is similar to the "Module Pattern". There are reasons to use it and reasons not to use it. Take a look here: [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)